# Copying a File using multi threading in parallel in c

Tags: c, multithreading, file, copy

I am trying to copy a file using threads in parallel. I don't want to use mutex and still be able to copy the file in the right order . As of now it is copying the file almost in the correct order for about 30-50 % of the file but then it goes haywire.  I think passing some parameter to the thread might be useful but I don't know what might be a useful parameter to pass to it.
I know it is pretty obvious that running threads in parallel while writing a file is not going to work. Is it a good idea to store the data of each thread somewhere and then write it. Are there any approaches to do the same. Any help is appreciated.

The problem seems to lie in the following part of the code.I have separated it for simplicity .I have added the entire code below.

```
    if(flg==0)
    {
      fpos_t position;
      fgetpos(fpp, &position);
    while((((e=(fread(strr,1,1,fpp)))>0)) || i<=lent)  
      { 
    fgetpos(fpp, &position);
    fwrite(strr,1,1,bck);
    i++;
    fsetpos(fpp, &position);
      }
    }
```

The entire code is added below. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
int counter;
static FILE * fpp;
static FILE * bck;
//pthread_mutex_t lock;
int wc;
int flag;
static int flg;
int lent;
unsigned long fsize(char* file)
{
  FILE * f = fopen(file, "rb+");
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
  unsigned long len = (unsigned long)ftell(f);
  fclose(f);
  return len;
}

void* doSomeThing(void* arg)
{
  //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  char str; 
  int i=0;
  counter++;
  char buff[100];
  bzero(buff,100);
  char strr[1];
  int e=0;
  bzero(strr,1);
  if(flg==0)
    {
      fpos_t position;
      //unsigned long len = (unsigned long)ftell(fpp);
      //fseek(fpp,len,SEEK_SET);
      fgetpos(fpp, &position);
    while((((e=(fread(strr,1,1,fpp)))>0)) || i<=lent)  
      { 
    fgetpos(fpp, &position);
    //len++;// = (unsigned long)ftell(fpp);
    fwrite(strr,1,1,bck);
    i++;
    fsetpos(fpp, &position);
    //fseek(fpp,len,SEEK_SET);
      }
    }
  if(e==0)
    {
      flg=1;
    }
  //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  return NULL;
}

int main()

{
  int i = 0;
  int err;

  char filn[100];
  printf("\nEnter Filename:");
  scanf("%s",filn);
  unsigned long len= fsize(filn);   
  lent=(int) len;
  lent=lent/5;
  printf("%lu",len);
  char backf[100];
  printf("\nEnter Filename to copy");
  scanf("%s",backf);
  bck=fopen(backf,"wb+");
  fpp=fopen(filn,"rb+");
  pthread_t tid[6];
  pthread_t * temp;
  fseek(fpp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  /*if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL)!=0)
    {
    printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
      return 1;
      }*/
  for(i=0;i<6;i++)
  err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
  //if (err != 0);
  int j=0;
  for(j=0;j<6;j++)
    {
      pthread_join(tid[j], NULL);
    }
  printf("\n%d",wc-1);    
  //pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
  fclose(bck);
  fclose(fpp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, what are you hoping to achieve by using multiple threads over a single thread?

Comment: I want to create a program which will generate a backup of a file having any format on the server side using multi threading. I have done the first part of it i.e. creating a backup but I am having some trouble with multithreading so I am trying first to do something which will copy a file using multithreading to understand how the original problem can be solved.

Comment: I am not that comfortable with threads. Please do let me know if I need to correct something. Thanks

Comment: @RED But as NPE asked, why are you using threads for simple copy operation? It will not speed up your copying.

Comment: Actually it was a part of a problem statement.The problem statement was to create a backup of a file on the server side which the client sends using multithreading. It is not my assignment. It is just that I wanted to try it.I don't know if it is something related to P2P but another problem was creating something similar to P2P where a file will be generated from multiple copies.

Comment: So basically you just want to see how to write different parts of one file from different threads?  Each thread will need to know what part of the file it's writing, they should write one at a time, and you should only open the file once.  Why can't you use a mutex?  You'll need *some* kind of synchronization...

Comment: I can't use a mutex because everything needs to be done in parallel.

Comment: You can't do the writes in parallel.. (well, maybe with low-level access to the disk... but that'd make things a lot more complicated with no real gain).  But the mutex wouldn't be locked for the whole life of the thread, just for file (or other shared resource) access.

Comment: @RED instead of approaching it like that, maybe you should have a look at memory mapped files, it would allow you to directly access a part of the file; otherwise the code has the risk of becoming a rube goldberg machine

Comment: @claptrap .I'll look it up.